# Opening Oracle 11g gives a "BAD GATEWAY ERROR"

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

When I open

```
http://localhost:8080/apex/f?p=4950
```

in Google Chrome it gives a `502 Bad gateway error`. How to correct it?

Answer (score 0):

Just clear whatever is in the cache memory of your browser and Everything will start working. Press Ctrl+H -> then clear browsing history->clear everything.

then open

```
http://localhost:8080/apex/f?p=4950
```

and it will work.